# R Studio is broken

Tags: rstudio

I have been using R Studio 0.98.983 in Debian Wheezy until yesterday. But today, when I opened R Studio it complains saying that couldn't find the .Rproject file and afterwards when I browse the files through the file panel all the files are grayed out and I cannot load anything.

I went to the official website to download a new version and it is just for Debian Jessie (and it doesn't work at all in Debian Wheezy. All the UI elements are in blank). In addition, R Studio cannot be found anymore in the Wheezy repositories.

I'm getting the impression that R Studio guys are getting Windowized in the sense that they are pushing people to move to the latest version of the OS. For those that we use computers to work (and not just to play), we trust more an old last stable version than a new buggy fashionable version of anything with which we have to spend hours figuring out how to make thinks work again. It's really a pity.

Any suggestions? Is there any working alternative to R Studio?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just use R directly without the R Studio IDE -- as far as non-IDE implementations go it is on the user-friendly side.

Answer (score 1):

We do in fact do our best to preserve backwards compatibility. Unfortunately, the newest release (0.99) builds on Qt 5.4, which requires a glibc newer than is present on Jessie. If you can't upgrade your glibc, then you can install an older RStudio build (try 0.98.1103):

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio-Desktop

We've heard that Qt is considering restoring compatibility with older glibc in an upcoming release, so hopefully we can too.